# Adding colorbar to matplotlib.axes.AxesSublot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 8 plots that I want to compare with 8 different but corresponding plots. So I set up 8 subplots, then try to use `axes_grid1.make_axes_locatable` to divide the subplots. However, it appears that when I use the `new_vertical` function it returns something of the type `matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot`.

Here's the code I have:

```
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(7):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4,2,i+1)
    idarray = ice_dict[i]
    mdarray = model_dict[i]
    side_by_side(ax, idarray, mdarray)


def side_by_side(ax1, idata, mdata):
  from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

  global mycmap
  global ice_dict, titles
  divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
  ax2 = divider.new_vertical(size="100%", pad=0.05)

  fig1 = ax1.get_figure()
  fig1.add_axes(ax2)

  cax1 = divider.append_axes("right", size = "5%", pad= 0.05)
  plt.sca(ax1)

  im1 = ax1.pcolor(idata, cmap = mycmap)

  ax1.set_xlim(space.min(), space.max()+1)
  ax1.set_ylim(0, len(idata))
  plt.colorbar(im1, cax=cax1)

  im2 = ax2.pcolor(mdata, cmap = mycmap)

  ax2.set_xlim(space.min(), space.max()+1)
  for tl in ax2.get_xticklabels():
      tl.set_visible(False)
  ax2.set_ylim(0, len(mdata))
  ax2.invert_yaxis()
```

Which produces something like this, where ax2 is on top and ax1 is on bottom in each subplot:

[image]

I should probably mention that they're on a different scale so I cant just use the same colorbar for both. Thanks in advance.

tl;dr how can I get a colorbar on ax2, an `AxesSubplot`, as well as ax1, an `Axes`? Or is there a better way to get the same look?